# JavaScript doesn't work in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to load a url by webView.
The url is http://wapp.baidu.com/f?kw=%BB%F0%BC%FD ,this page can work correctly on system default browser, but in my webView, some JavaScript not working.
JavaScript is enabled, and I dont know what's wrong with it.

I would appreciate any help.

```
private void initUI() {
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    final NavigationBar navigationBar = (NavigationBar) findViewById(R.id.navigationbar);
    navigationBar.refreshUI();
    navigationBar.rightButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.refresh);
    navigationBar.rightButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    navigationBar.rightButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            refresh();
        }

    });

    navigationBar.leftButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
    navigationBar.leftButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            webView.goBack();
        }

    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            navigationBar.leftButton.setVisibility(webView.canGoBack() ? View.VISIBLE
                    : View.INVISIBLE);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });

    refresh();
}
```

update: the problem is solved
just add following code:

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: What the api version of you device on which you are testing this?

Comment: @AliImran the device is Nexus S with Android 4.1.1, do you mean this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using proguard, it stops javascript running. For instance, in my proguard-project.txt file I have the following:

```
if your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

Comment: how do you use it? I mean you just remove # signs from class:? or should copy onto a code block?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some issue with javascript file caching/refreshing. I changed the filename of js & it starts working fine.