# Javascript doesn't work on Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Good Day,

I have a webview in Android app which loads a resource that uses html and javascript:

```
WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
//webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
//webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
//webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
//webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});

//webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Index.html");
webView.loadUrl("http://foo.com/newbilltemplate/");
```

The comments show you what I've tried so far. Also I tried local and online resource and the problem still exist.

The index.html page doesn't use Javascript but when  a button is clicked it uses some Javascript calculations to display in the next page.

Thanks,

Comment: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667890/javascript-doesnt-work-in-android-webview)

Comment: I changed proguard-rules.pro to this:
-keepclassmembers class om.com.electricity.billapp.MainActivity {public *;}
still dosn't work

Comment: Use the first two lines of your code at the same time: `WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` `WebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);`. It would be helpful to see what kind of javascript you're trying to execute.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I don't know if this matters but I've the .js file in a folder that exists in the same directory of index.html and the other pages that use javascript.

Comment: I don't know what u mean by what kind of javascript statosdotcom. But this is one of the functions i'm using:      

 function getTariffType(place) {
    var type = "";

    if (place == 1) {
        type = "سكني/حكومي" + '\n' + "Resid.\\Gov.";
    }
    else if (place == 2) {
        type = "تجاري &#13; Commercial";
    }
    else {
        type = "سياحي &#13;Tourism";
    }

    return type;
}

Comment: note the position of the javaScript file.`.` means current directory, and `../`means parent directory.